# How to add Ellipsis at End and Middle in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Want to apply Ellipsis like this at end and middle

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSTtR.png]

Answer (score 0):

Enabling end ellipses is pretty simple:

```
Text(text, overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis)
```

There's no built in feature for the middle one, you can star [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/185418980) to get notified when it's done. For now [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69084973/3585796) can be used.