# Set Ellipsis at the start (left) of the text in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I want to set the ellipsis in the start of the text compose when the text is overflow like this picture below:

[image]

However, I did created with the ellipsis property of the compose. The result was not correct:

[image]

Here the code I tried:

```
        // current week text
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.dp_6)))
                .background(Color.White)
                .padding(
                    vertical = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.dp_8),
                    horizontal = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.dp_10)
                )
                .singleClick(isShowClickEffect = false) {
                    onCurrentWeekTextTapped()
                }
        ) {
            Text(
                text = currentWeekText,
                style = LGAppTypography.mobileBodyMedium,
                color = colorResource(id = R.color.Color_11161D),
                fontWeight = FontWeight.W400,
                maxLines = 1,
                **overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,**
            )
        }
```

Comment: Add ... to the text, and set overflow to `TextOverflow.Clip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Note! I did it for AppBar***
By changing [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69084973/23400558) a bit
I got this:

```
@Composable
fun StartEllipsisText(
    text: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    color: Color = Color.Unspecified,
    fontSize: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    fontStyle: FontStyle? = null,
    fontWeight: FontWeight? = null,
    fontFamily: FontFamily? = null,
    letterSpacing: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    textDecoration: TextDecoration? = null,
    textAlign: TextAlign? = null,
    lineHeight: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    softWrap: Boolean = true,
    onTextLayout: (TextLayoutResult) -> Unit = {},
    style: TextStyle = LocalTextStyle.current,
) {
    val layoutText = remember(text) { "$text $ellipsisText" }
    val textLayoutResultState = remember(layoutText) { mutableStateOf<TextLayoutResult?>(null) }

    SubcomposeLayout(modifier) { constraints ->
        subcompose("measure") {
            Text(
                text = layoutText,
                color = color,
                fontSize = fontSize,
                fontStyle = fontStyle,
                fontWeight = fontWeight,
                fontFamily = fontFamily,
                letterSpacing = letterSpacing,
                textDecoration = textDecoration,
                textAlign = textAlign,
                lineHeight = lineHeight,
                softWrap = softWrap,
                maxLines = 1,
                onTextLayout = { textLayoutResultState.value = it },
                style = style,
            )
        }.first().measure(Constraints())

        val textLayoutResult =
            textLayoutResultState.value ?: return@SubcomposeLayout layout(0, 0) {}
        val placeable = subcompose("visible") {
            val finalText = remember(text, textLayoutResult, constraints.maxWidth) {
                if (
                    text.isEmpty() ||
                    textLayoutResult.getBoundingBox(text.indices.last).right <= constraints.maxWidth
                ) {
                    return@remember text
                }

                val ellipsisWidth = layoutText.indices.toList()
                    .takeLast(ellipsisCharactersCount)
                    .let widthLet@{ indices ->
                        for (i in indices) {
                            val width = textLayoutResult.getBoundingBox(i).width
                            if (width > 0) {
                                return@widthLet width * ellipsisCharactersCount
                            }
                        }
                        throw IllegalStateException("all ellipsis chars have invalid width")
                    }
                val availableWidth = constraints.maxWidth - ellipsisWidth
                val endCounter = BoundCounter(text, textLayoutResult) { text.indices.last - it }
                while (availableWidth - endCounter.width > 0) {
                    val possibleEndWidth = endCounter.widthWithNextChar()
                    if (availableWidth - possibleEndWidth >= 0) {
                        endCounter.addNextChar()
                    } else {
                        break
                    }
                }
                ellipsisText + endCounter.string.reversed().trimStart()
            }

            Text(
                text = finalText,
                color = color,
                fontSize = fontSize,
                fontStyle = fontStyle,
                fontWeight = fontWeight,
                fontFamily = fontFamily,
                letterSpacing = letterSpacing,
                textDecoration = textDecoration,
                textAlign = textAlign,
                lineHeight = lineHeight,
                softWrap = softWrap,
                onTextLayout = onTextLayout,
                style = style,
            )
        }[0].measure(constraints)
        layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
            placeable.place(0, 0)
        }
    }
}

private const val ellipsisCharactersCount = 3
private const val ellipsisCharacter = '.'
private val ellipsisText =
    List(ellipsisCharactersCount) { ellipsisCharacter }.joinToString(separator = "")

private class BoundCounter(
    private val text: String,
    private val textLayoutResult: TextLayoutResult,
    private val charPosition: (Int) -> Int,
) {
    var string = ""
        private set
    var width = 0f
        private set

    private var _nextCharWidth: Float? = null
    private var invalidCharsCount = 0

    fun widthWithNextChar(): Float =
        width + nextCharWidth()

    private fun nextCharWidth(): Float =
        _nextCharWidth ?: run {
            var boundingBox: Rect
            invalidCharsCount--
            do {
                boundingBox = textLayoutResult
                    .getBoundingBox(charPosition(string.count() + ++invalidCharsCount))
            } while (boundingBox.right == 0f)
            _nextCharWidth = boundingBox.width
            boundingBox.width
        }

    fun addNextChar() {
        string += text[charPosition(string.count())]
        width += nextCharWidth()
        _nextCharWidth = null
    }
}
```